# how we can compile pjsip-2.5.5 with opus codec for android multiple architectures

Tags: android, makefile, android-ndk, pjsip, opus

I am working on pjsip and trying to compile pjsip for android with ndk . I follow instructions from [PJSIP FOR ANDROID](https://github.com/VoiSmart/pjsip-android-builder) . I did it successfully with g729 but now I want to use opus but there have no documentation Please anyone help me how we can compile pjsip with opus for android (different - different archs).

Answer (score 0):

Try this [repo](https://github.com/VoiSmart/pjsip-android-builder) to build PJSIP. It is pretty simple to build it from here.
You just need to chnage in config the PJSIP version from 2.4.5 to 2.5.5.

And to add opus follow this simple steps from [this ticket](https://trac.pjsip.org/repos/ticket/1904). It worked for me.